# iostat - print only current stats without the sumary since boot

Tags: linux, centos, performance, disk, io

I want to get the read and write, service time, queue length and wait time of my disks. the OS is CentOS 6. I use `iostat`.  when I run this command:

`iostat -x -d /dev/sda`

the output is:

```
 Device: rrqm/s  wrqm/s  r/s  w/s  rsec/s  wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz  await  svctm  %util  
 sda     4.04   272.41   21.63  58.30  7565.96  3037.79   132.66 0.06    0.74   0.66 5.26
```

which return the total value since system been up. but I want disk information at time. for that I should run `iostat -x -d /dev/sda 1 2`.
the output is :

```
Device:   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  r/s  w/s  rsec/s  wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await svctm  %util
sda   4.04  272.40 21.63  58.30  7565.86  3037.75   132.66  0.06 0.74   0.66   5.26
Device:  rrqm/s wrqm/s  r/s  w/s   rsec/s wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda  0.00    11.00   0.00  12.00   0.00   184.00   15.33    0.32   26.75   3.08   3.70
```

which the second part shows what I want. is there any way to get that information directly without `1 2`? I searched man page but didn't find anything. Or is there any other way to get that information instead of `iostat`? (and I cant install new packages on systems -_-).

Comment: Would piping through a filter be acceptable?

Comment: can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pipe it through `sed`:

```
iostat -x -d /dev/sda 1 2 | sed '1,2d'
Device:  rrqm/s wrqm/s  r/s  w/s   rsec/s wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda  0.00    11.00   0.00  12.00   0.00   184.00   15.33    0.32   26.75   3.08   3.70
```

Comment: did you test it? when i ran that command it didnt work!

Comment: "didnt work" is not something people can build some troubleshooting upon. Please be more precise. I tested by `cat`ting your output file through the `sed` command. You might want to do the same.

Comment: yes youre right. it didnt work i meant it returned both parts.i will try by `cat`. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-y` switch:

> Omit first report with statistics since system boot, if displaying multiple records at given interval.

with a `1 1` interval/repeat, so

```
iostat -y -x -d /dev/sda 1 1
```